# Length of symmetric difference of two intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, interval-arithmetic

I have two intervals characterized by the pairs $a,b$ and $c,d$, all numbers larger than zero:

$$S_1 = (\min(a,b), \max(a,b))$$
$$S_2 = (\min(c,d), \max(c,d))$$

The length $s$ of an interval is defined in the usual way: $s( (x,y)) = y-x$, so that $s(S_1) = |b-a|$ and $s(S_2) = |d-c|$, and the length of a union of disjoint intervals is the sum of lengths. The length does not change when using closed intervals.

My aim is to find a compact form for the length of the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) $\Delta$ of $S_1$ and $S_2$ (i.e. the union without the intersection; $S_1 \cup S_2 - S_1 \cap S_2$); that is, what is $s(S_1 \Delta S_2)$?

---

With a little trial and error, I've found the following formula that seems to work pretty generally:

$$s(S_1 \Delta S_2) = |\max(\min(a,b),\max(c,d)) - \max(\max(a,b),\min(c,d))| + |\min(\min(a,b),\max(c,d)) - \min(\max(a,b),\min(c,d))|$$

For example, with $(a,b) = (1,3)$ and $(c,d) = (2,5)$, the symmetric difference is $(1,2]\cup[3,5)$, and the length of the symmetric difference is $1+2 = 3$. The intuition behind this formula is that the first absolute value finds the "right overhang" (length of $[3,5)$, which is $2$) and the second absolute value finds the "left overhang" (length of $[1,2)$, which is $1$).

However, this formula seems more than a little unnecessarily complicated. Is there a simplification, especially one with fewer $\min$ and $\max$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about
$$
s=\max\{a,b,c,d\}-\min\{a,b,c,d\}-|\max\{a,b,c,d\}-\min\{a,b,c,d\}-s(S_1)-s(S_2)|?
$$

Comment: +1. It looks like $s(S_1)+s(S_2)−(\max \{a,b,c,d\}−\min\{a,b,c,d\})$ is positive iff there's overlap, in which case it's the overlap. Then, when there's overlap, calculating the length of the smallest interval containing $S_1$ and $S_2$, $(\max \{a,b,c,d\}−\min\{a,b,c,d\})$, and then subtracting the overlap gives the length in the symmetric difference. If there is no overlap, then the answer must reduce to $s(S_1)+s(S_2)$, which it does when the argument of the absolute value is negative. I'll give 24 hours then I'll accept as I expect this is the simplest.

Comment: Sounds good. There may be a simpler one, I do not know..

Comment: As an aside, I think if one defines $w,x,y,z$ = $sort(a,b,c,d)$ where $sort$ sorts from largest to smallest, then $w-x+y-z$ will work.